# How can I make my own bst file or where can I learn the language?

Tags: bibliographies, bibliographystyle, bst

I've been asked to have my references in a specific style that does not seem to match any of the styles that I've come across. I've tried to see if any of the default styles or styles in biblatex package match with the one I must have but none of the do, so I want to make my own bst file but I don't understand the language.

Comment: `texdoc beast` should open up the nice "tame the b(ea)st" tuorial

Comment: A great resource for BibTeX is http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf. But, given your description, you probably want to take a look at `makebst`: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/makebst.pdf.

Comment: official manual is `texdoc btxhak`